# Custom TreeViewItem Structure

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've to create a custom tree structure which should looks like:

> ```
> -Start
> --Process
> --Decision
> ---DecisionOption
> ----Process
> ----Process
> ---DecisionOption
> ----Process
> ```

Each of these Types has a set of custom attributes. Basically a TreeViewItem structure works fine and the 'hierarquical facilities' (like get parent and childs) within is a plus.
What is 'best' way to do it?

I did some ways but I'm having problem when trying to apply HierarquicalDataTemplates. (e.g.). It simply doesn't work.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Start}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
 <Border >
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
 </Border>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Any ideias how to implement that structure?

Answer (score 0):

[This shows the multi-tiered Treeview](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1401031/Using-the-WPF-Tree-View-with-Multiple-Levels) --  [Here is a step by step usage of HierarchicalDataTemplate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step/)
As Mike indicates in the second article the HDT does not exactly program itself.  Follow his steps for using it to create an East/West conference list and you should have your answer as what to do.